How do I get my adult cats to get along with my new adult cat I adopted 6 month's ago
My partner and I adopted a 4yo male cat 6 months ago
We bought him into our home that already had a 1yo male cat and a 2yo male cat.
It has been 6 months and my resident cats are still fighting the new cat. I tried swapping out scents but one of my resident cats just kept peeing on the new cats things so I couldn't keep doing this. Sometimes they can sit on the same room together but usually the resident cats jump on on the new cat and scare him and attack him causing sores and stress to the new cat. I have no idea what to do please help
I also have put a feliway diffuser in the hallway

Are the cats neutered? The peeing on stuff makes me assume they are sexually intact. Intact male cats are known to be very territorial and intolerant towards other intact males. As long as you don't have all of them neutered, I see no chance of them ever living peacefully together. Also consider that cats - just like humans - have their own personalities and they may simply dislike the new cat. That's also nothing that can be easily changed.

There are a number of past answers regarding introducing cats to each other. I presume you have reviewed those...

Questions about introducing a new cat: https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=introduce+new+cat Please come back with information about what you tried, what happened and what exactly you want to solve (one point of behaviour, one question or similar)
